# Is there a better way than this to force monitor blank/off?

Tags: linux, power-management, monitors, screen-energy-saving

Intending to switch off the display/monitor/screen instantly (and only be reenabled upon keypress) I resort to this solution:

- a `/bin/blankvt` script:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  echo 1 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/graphics/fb0/blank
  read keypress
  chvt 2
  ```
- a `/bin/blank` script:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  openvt -s -f -c 40 /bin/blankvt
  ```

Having setup this I can simply call `blank` on the command line and the
screen will go off and energy is saved. Great!

While this solution works right now, it appears hackish and brittle and what I seek is the correct way to achieve the same effect. 
Typing `blank` at the shell prompt should result in the screen to be turned off.

My question hence: how can I switch of the monitor "*correctly*"?

**Background/Motivation**

I am not connected to the electrical grid, conserving energy is paramount to me. I need to have the laptop/PC do some calculations but would desire to turn off the superflous energy consumption by the display (which seems a non neglectible consumer anyway).

Best if I could achieve this within:

- GNOME Shell 3.32.2.
- Linux 5.xx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you’re using X,

```
xset dpms force off
```

will switch the display off.

Under Wayland with GNOME, you can activate the screensaver, which will blank the screen if it’s configured to do so normally:

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver --type=method_call \
          /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.SetActive boolean:true
```

You can also lock your session with <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, which will have the same effect if your session is configured to blank the screen when the screensaver is on.

Comment: thanks for providing solutions for both wayland and Xserver. I makes me realize that I sort of forgot to clarify wich display server/protocol I use. But I guess that makes the answer even better it provides for both Xorg and Wayland. I use mostly wayland. And the dbus thing worked like a charm! thanks